# Fxml set styleclass from source

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have class with final static fields :

```
package com.a.b;

public class MyVars {
    public static final String S1 = "s1";
    public static final String S2 = "s2";
    ....
}
```

And I want to set styleClass property for button from this class. Inside fxml file, I do :

```
<?import  com.a.b.MyVars?> // import my class

<Button fx:id="myBtn">
   <styleClass>
      <String fx:value=MyVars.S1 />  //here error
      <String fx:value=MyVars.S2 />
   </styleClass>
</Button>
```

But I have got the error :

> Message: Open quote is expected for attribute "fx:value" associated
>   with an  element type  "String".

I try to write different versions, but always got a error.

How I can write styleClass ( or another attribute) via link from source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`<fx:constant>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#constant_elements):

```xml
<?import  com.a.b.MyVars?> // import my class

<Button fx:id="myBtn">
   <styleClass>
      <MyVars fx:constant="S1" />  //here error
      <MyVars fx:constant="S2" />
   </styleClass>
</Button>
```

Comment: Oh,  after write post i try it and it's work. Want to close/answer post and see your answer. Thanks,it's work.